# Validating max size of Array parameter

Tags: python, arrays, validation

I'm practicing data structures and trying to make an Array class. I'm also trying to validate the parameter. Is there a better or more Pythonic way of initializing the class?

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        if not isinstance(max_size, int):
            raise TypeError(f"'{type(max_size).__name__}' object cannot be interpreted as an integer")
        elif max_size < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Please pass in a non-negative integer')
        else:
            self.maxsize = max_size
            self.items = [None for _ in range(max_size)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears correct.  Beyond that it's a question of style.  You correctly raise the right exceptions.  You could potentially write some helper functions to simplify such validations if you are going to do a lot of them.

```
def assert_integer(i):
    if not isinstance(i, int):
        raise TypeError(i.__class__.__name__+' could not be interpreted as an
```

integer)

Then in your constructor

```
assert_integer(i)
```

One disadvantage of such helper functions is that they will make the traceback longer.